# Generating a PNG image of chart from json file

Tags: highcharts

I am displaying the contents of a large database in a Highcharts chart and I would like to capture the image of the graph automatically, say at 9pm daily, and save the image in a file.  I have tried to install the server-side export server solution, but I have been unable to make it work on the raspberry pi.

As an alternative, I have captured the json used to generate the graph in a file.  Can I send the file to Highcharts and get a PNG image in return?  How, exactly, should I do this?
Thanks.

The json file contains the following.  This is exactly the same json that is passed to the browser and results in a proper graph:

```
[{
    "name": "Consumed",
    "data": [
        [1521612002000, 668],
        [1521612182000, 668],
        [1521634338000, 487]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "Paid For",
    "data": [
        [1521612002000, 668],
        [1521612182000, 668],
        [1521634338000, 75]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "Produced",
    "data": [
        [1521612002000, 0],
        [1521612182000, 0],
        [1521634338000, 412]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "Paid For kWh",
    "data": [
        [1521612002000, null],
        [1521615425000, 0.6118],
        [1521634338000, null]
    ]
}]
```

I have tried the following curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile": combined_readings.json}' http://export.highcharts.com > file.png
```

It resulted in the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 11<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.parse (native)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emitNone (events.js:86:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
```

With the help of highcharts support I was able to resolve several issues:
   - the curl command requires a json string (as noted in the comments)
   - the json string needs to be reformatted from that required by the browser

Here is the reformatted json string:

```
{
  "series": [{
    "name": "Consumed",
    "data": [
      [1521612002000, 668],
      [1521612182000, 668],
      [1521634338000, 487]
    ]
},  {
    "name": "Paid For",
    "data": [
      [1521612002000, 668],
      [1521612182000, 668],
      [1521634338000, 75]
    ]
},  {
    "name": "Produced",
    "data": [
      [1521612002000, 0],
      [1521612182000, 0],
      [1521634338000, 412]
    ]
},  {
    "name": "Paid For kWh",
    "data": [
      [1521612002000, null],
      [1521615425000, 0.6118],
      [1521634338000, null]
    ]
  }]
}
```

The curl command required looks like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"infile\": \"{series: [{name: 'Consumed',data: [[1521612002000, 668],[1521612182000, 668],[1521634338000, 487]]}, {name: 'Paid For',data: [[1521612002000, 668],[1521612182000, 668],[1521634338000, 75]]}, {name: 'Produced',data: [[1521612002000, 0],[1521612182000, 0],[1521634338000, 412]]}, {name: 'Paid For kWh',data: [[1521612002000, null],[1521615425000, 0.6118],[1521634338000, null]]}]}\"}" export.highcharts.com > chart.png
```

Comment: You can send it to export.highcharts.com - see the API docs here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: Yes, I read through those docs, but they don't address what I am trying to do.  I think I need a curl command that passes a file containing json (the same json that is passed to the client-side browser) to the highcharts export service and returns a png file.  Is this doable?

Comment: It looks like you json is not a valid one...i just check it into this site https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The json above is now correct (validated on jsonlint.com), and results in the same error.

Comment: Chart options should be string - see the examples with curl here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside